# Custom field in TFS 2010 does not appear in Team Web Access

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I used the TFS 2010 Power Tools to create a custom field for a Task. The custom field shows nicely inside Visual Studio 2010 on my machine and a coworkers machine.

However, when I go to Team Web Access in my browser, the new field does not appear in the form. I can change the value of my custom field using VS 2010.

The "Field Changes" section will display my changed value of my custom field in the browser.

The problem is that the editor control for the custom field doesn't appear in the browser, it only appears in VS 2010. Therefore, anyone using Team Web Access cannot edit my custom field.

Is there something more I need to do to make this custom field visible in Team Web Access? Is it a cache issue that will resolve itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to refresh the cache of TWA. You can do that in the Settings menu (at the right hand side of the screen) and then choose Refresh Cache.
A second cause could be that there are two different form layouts specified. One for the Windows and one for the Web. Check whether this is the case. The easiest way to do this is by editing the WIT in an xml editor (could be visual studio - choose the Open With option) and see if there is a "Windows" layout and a "Web" layout.

Comment: Brilliant! An hour has passed since I asked the question and you answered it. During that time, the cache must have expired and the field appeared in Team Web Access. However, I found the Refresh Cache menu item you described. Thanks!!